# Thunar's "Open Terminal here" bug

Tags: terminal, thunar, xfce4-terminal

I'm using Thunar 1.8.2 on Debian Testing and the "Open Terminal here" function seems buggy.

I've set up the custom action `xfce4-terminal --working-directory=%f` with the keyboard shortcut `F4`.

Oddly enough, right-click in Thunar and "Open Terminal here" always seems to work. That opens the xfce4-terminal with the current working directory.

But with `F4` it always opens the terminal with the directory I last used the right-click "Open Terminal here".

So for example, in Thunar I go to `/tmp/`, right-click, "Open Terminal here", I get a Terminal with `/tmp/` as the current working directory. I close the terminal, move to `/home/` in Thunar, then press `F4` and I get a Terminal with `/tmp/` as the current working directory again.

How do I fix this behavior?

*edit:* This is the current configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz6wG.png

Comment: hello and thanks @GAD3R. I've edited the question and added a screenshot of the current configuration. I believe I have everything set up as you describe it.

Comment: @GAD3R The command I use works fine. I don't have a full-blown DE like xfce4 so your command results in the following for me: https://i.imgur.com/rPtWVta.png

Comment: I don't have any other shortcut mapped for F4 and I don't have a settings manager. As I said I don't use a DE.

Comment: Remove working-directory and keep only xfce4-terminal

Comment: @ctac_ oh wow! marvelous! How/why is this the case? Thank you so much! If you want to form an answer, I'll gladly approve it

Comment: I think it's like a lot of other program. If you don't give a path, it take the current path. You can try with a custom action like ls > dir.txt and you get a file dir.txt in the current directory.If you want to know more about xfce4-terminal, you can ask here:https://forum.xfce.org/index.php .

Answer (score 0):

With Thunar v4.16.10 on Debian Sid, I only use `x-terminal-emulator` **with no** `%[letter]` **parameter whatsoever**, and it works *perfectly*.

Notes:

1. The `x-terminal-emulator` environment variable is set to `/usr/bin/terminator` on my system, but it works with `rxvt-unicode` as well (or `urxvt`), for instance;
2. On any Debian-based system, use `update-alternatives` (as root) to set the default terminal emulator you want to use. It should work with most terminal emulators.